# CSS3 transforms and transitions (Webkit)

Tags: css, webkit, css-transitions, css-transforms

Consider the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6TMcS/)

```
p {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
     -moz-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
      -ms-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
       -o-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
          transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  -webkit-transition: transform 1s ease-in;
     -moz-transition: transform 1s ease-in;
       -o-transition: transform 1s ease-in;
          transition: transform 1s ease-in;
}

a:hover + p {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
     -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
      -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
       -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
          transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

The transition works smoothly in FF but there is no transition at all in Safari or Chrome (on my Mac).

Has the transition property to be prefixed or is there some kind of syntax error in my code?

Comment: use prefixfreejs to make your life easy

Comment: The syntax highlighting looks weird (it is probably a problem with syntax highlighting itself).

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Add the vendor prefix in the transitions:

```
p {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
     -moz-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
      -ms-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
       -o-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
          transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in; /* Changed here */ 
     -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s ease-in;
       -o-transition: -o-transform 1s ease-in;
          transition: transform 1s ease-in;
}

a:hover + p {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
     -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
      -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
       -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
          transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

**Update (05/06/2014)**

To answer some comments, the reason for omitting `-ms-transition`, is that it has never existed.

Check:

[Can I Use? Transitions](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions),

[Can I Use? Transforms](http://caniuse.com/transforms2d),

[MDN transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition#Browser_compatibility),

[MDN transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Of course I just added the -webkit- prefix because your complain was about Safari and Chrome. You should add the prefix for -moz- and the rest, but based on what you said, FF doesn't need it.

Comment: Yeah, obviously.I didn't find any documentation on that. In all resources I found the transition property is non-prefixed.

Comment: I just knew it had to work, but I didn't find any direct example, also. The closest thing was this: http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-transition-property , in which you can see that the <name> has to be the same name as the CSS rule...in this case with the vendor prefix. Cheers

Comment: Well, that edit by @gregory renders my first comment obsolete. I only changed the webkit line on purpose, but nonetheless, I think the edited version might be more useful to future visitors.

Comment: What about applying a `transition` to `-ms-transform`?

Comment: It's a secret ploy to artificially diminish IE's featureset.

Comment: @sompylasar Well, I didn't apply a `transition` to `-ms-transform`, because that's basically impossible. `-ms-transition` has never existed, afaik. You can only use `transition` on IE >= 10 and `transform` is also available on IE >= 10. `-ms-transform` is only used on IE9.
[CanIUse Transitions](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions),
[CanIUse Transforms](http://caniuse.com/transforms2d),
[MDN Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition#Browser_compatibility),
[MDN Transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility)