# -webkit-transition has no effect when followed by transition with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Problem**

I am setting transitions for transform similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13782443/746754). On Chrome, I found that when I set the css `-webkit-transition` before `transition` with a transform then the transition for the transform does not work (the transform happens immediately rather than over 5 seconds - see demo later):

```
$img.css('-webkit-transition', '-webkit-transform 5s');        
$img.css('transition', 'transform 5s');//move this line before the previous line and it works
```

**Workarounds**

The following does work though:

- Move the second line before the first.
- Comment the second line out.
- Use JavaScript (I expected this to do exactly the same as the jQuery code, but it works):

  ```
  img.style.setProperty("-webkit-transition", "-webkit-transform 5s");
  img.style.setProperty("transition", "transform 5s");
  ```
- Use css class and then `addClass`:

  ```
  .transformStyle
  {
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 5s;
      transition: transform 5s;
      ....
  ```

**Demo**

You can see a demo of these different cases **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/M3cZk/6/)**.

**Info**

When I look at element.style in Chrome dev tools for the jQuery case I get:

```
-webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(30deg);
```

(there is not transition style at all).

For jQuery with the line commented I get:

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 5s;
transition: -webkit-transform 5s;
-webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(30deg);
```

For JavaScript I get:

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 5s;
transition: -webkit-transform 5s;
-webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(60deg);
```

So, it seems that when I comment out the line in jQuery the `transform` is set to `-webkit-transform` which also happens with JavaScript even though I explicitly set it just to `transform`.

**Questions**

- what is happening with the jQuery case? Why does setting `$img.css('transition', 'transform 5s');` cause there to be no transition at all. Why does moving this line before the `-webkit-transition` line cause things to suddenly work?
- Why is transform being automatically set to '-webkit-transform' for JavaScript?

Either I am missing something or Chrome / jQuery / JavaScript are doing something under the hood. I have a workaround which is to use JavaScript, but I would be interested to know what is happening in case it is something that could crop up elsewhere with webkit/jQuery. I had a look around and at the [MDN page for transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions), but did not find anything.

Comment: Moving the Line above will work depending on your browser and as you are using -webkit-transform it will take transform automatically in chrome.

Comment: @Alpesh, why does the same order that does not work in jQuery work in JavaScript and css class?

Answer (score 0):

As Per you First link

```
p {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
     -moz-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
      -ms-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
       -o-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
          transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in; /* Changed here */ 
     -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s ease-in;
       -o-transition: -o-transform 1s ease-in;
          transition: transform 1s ease-in;
}

a:hover + p {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
     -moz-transform: translate(0, 0);
      -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
       -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
          transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

You cannot use the transform directly in your css as you need to change it by some event i.e hover then you will able to get the transform in your code using javascript also.

Above css will work fine as it changes the transform on hover event.

Comment: both JavaScript and css classes work fine in my code. The problem is that the same settings don't work in jQuery, as per the demo I provided.

Comment: i set  both to 60deg from 30deg and it's working fine for jQuery fails $img.css('-webkit-transform', 'perspective(400px) rotateX(60deg)'); $img.css('transform', 'perspective(400px) rotateX(60deg)');

Comment: I am able to make it work, that is not what I am asking. What I am asking is: 1) What is happening with the jQuery case that makes it different? 2) Why is transform being automatically set to '-webkit-transform' for JavaScript? I suspect that there is something going on under the hood, but I am not clear on what.

Comment: img.style.setProperty is setting up the style property and $img.css is replacing the css with the latest property applied in the javascript so it can make difference and if you run this on chrome it will convert to '-webkit-transform' from 'transform' and in firefox it will take the same code that you had used so it is only for chrome if you want to use it in chrome then you need to use only '-webkit-transform'.